# How to make JoyUI assume a specific html font size?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, joy-ui

I have a React app using JoyUI running in a shadow DOM (because it's a chrome extension content script).

When the `font-size` of some web page that the extension is running in is set to eg. 14px instead of 16px, my shadow DOM content script UI changes size. This is because the JoyUI CSS variables are based on `rem`, which is always inherited from the root html element and can't be changed just for the shadow DOM (eg. by setting `font-size: initial;` on the shadow DOM root).

How can I force JoyUI to always use 16px as the standard font size?

In MUI (not JoyUI) it's possible to [manually set the `htmlFontSize`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#html-font-size) in a custom theme.

Is there a way to do something similar in JoyUI?

Comment: If you won't find such a method, consider putting the UI inside an iframe.